# Skip reading header of text file in C

Tags: c, file-io

I am reading in data from a file `orderedfile.txt`. Sometimes this file has a header of the form:

```
BEGIN header

       Real Lattice(A)               Lattice parameters(A)    Cell Angles
   2.4675850   0.0000000   0.0000000     a =    2.467585  alpha =   90.000000
   0.0000000  30.0000000   0.0000000     b =   30.000000  beta  =   90.000000
   0.0000000   0.0000000  30.0000000     c =   30.000000  gamma =   90.000000

 1                            ! nspins
25   300   300                ! fine FFT grid along <a,b,c>
END header: data is "<a b c> pot" in units of Hartrees

 1     1     1            0.042580
 1     1     2            0.049331
 1     1     3            0.038605
 1     1     4            0.049181
```

and sometimes no header is present and the data starts on the first line. My code for reading in the data is shown below. It works when the data starts on line one, but not with the header present. Is there a way to get around this?

```
int readinputfile() {
   FILE *potential = fopen("orderedfile.txt", "r");
   for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
      fscanf(potential, "%lf %lf %*f  %lf", &x[i], &y[i], &V[i]);
   }
   fclose(potential);
}
```

Comment: Switch to reading whole lines. That allows you to detect the header and then read until data starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will use [fgets()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to read each line. For each line [sscanf()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) is used to scan the string and store it into double variables.
See a running [example (with stdin) at ideone](https://ideone.com/rayK96).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   /* maybe the buffer must be greater */
   char lineBuffer[256];
   FILE *potential = fopen("orderedfile.txt", "r");

   /* loop through every line */
   while (fgets(lineBuffer, sizeof(lineBuffer), potential) != NULL)
   {
      double a, b, c;
      /* if there are 3 items matched print them */
      if (3 == sscanf(lineBuffer, "%lf %lf %*f %lf", &a, &b, &c))
      {
         printf("%f %f %f\n", a, b, c);
      }
   }
   fclose(potential);

   return 0;
}
```

It is working with the header you provided but if in the header a line such as:

```
 1     1     2            0.049331
```

would appear then this line would also be read. Another possibility would be to search for the word `END header` if `BEGIN header` is present as it is in your given header or use a line count if the number of lines is known.
To search for sub strings the function [strstr()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/) could be used.

Answer (score 2):

Check the return value of `fscanf`. If it returns three, your input was correct; otherwise, you are still in the header, so you must skip the line:

```
int readinputfile() {
    FILE *potential = fopen("orderedfile.txt", "r");
    int res;
    while(res = fscanf(potential, "%lf %lf %*f %lf", &x[i], &y[i], &V[i])) {
        if (res != 3) {
            fscanf(potential, "%*[^\n]");
            continue;
        }
        i++;
        ... // Optionally, do anything else with the data that you read
    }
    fclose(potential);
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/ThllQn)

Comment: @chqrlie Sure - the function isn't all that big, so I added the remaining parts. Thanks!

Comment: Final fix is to add i = i - 1 term to stop incrementation of loop when skipping lines!

Answer (score 2):

I'd think it's a lot more reliable to explicitly look for the header's beginning and ending than it is to rely on no string in the header ever matching a `scanf()`-style format string:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(...);

int inHeader = 0;

size_t lineLen = 128;
char *linePtr = malloc( lineLen );

// skip header lines
while ( getline( &linePtr, &lineLen, fp ) >= ( ssize_t ) 0 )
{
    // check for the start of the header (need to do this first to
    // catch the first line)
    if ( !inHeader )
    {
        inHeader = !strncmp( linePtr, "BEGIN header", strlen( "BEGIN header" ) );
    }
    else
    {
        // if we were in the header, check for the end line and go to next line
        inHeader = strncmp( linePtr, "END header", strlen( "END header" ) );

        // need to skip this line no matter what because it's in the header
        continue;
    }

    // if we're not in the header, either break this loop
    // which leaves the file at the first non-header line,
    // or process the line in this loop
    if ( !inHeader )
    {
        ...
    }
}
...
```

You may prefer using `strstr()` instead of `strncmp()`.  That way the header begin/end strings don't have to start the line.

Comment: Why the `malloc()` call? `size_t lineLen = 0; char *linePtr = NULL;` is perfectly fine for POSIX.1 [`getline()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html).

Comment: @NominalAnimal *Why the `malloc()` call?*  Just to avoid line lengths slowly growing the buffer over multiple calls.  Not anything that really matters.